# mask the first five digits of a SSN with asterisks

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

I want to rewrite the SSN # such that the first five numbers are replaced with asterisks

this is how the csv file looks:

```
Emp ID,Name,DOB,SSN,State
15,Samantha Lara,1993-09-08,848-80-7526,Colorado
```

this is what the expected data should look like:

```
15,Samantha,Lara,09/08/1993,***-**-7526,CO
```

Here is the code I have thus far, but am unsure how to mask those numbers

```
# create a list to store the data from csv file
empl_ssn = []

reform_ssn = row["3"]
reform_ssn = ........
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're looping through the data and writing that line by line to the desired output file. If that's the case, then simply join two strings together splitting the SSN for the last 5 characters and a preset string.

```
new_ssn = "***-**-" + row["3"].split(7)
```

Though in a row, it looks like the SSN is at the 4th index.

Pro Tip: If you're talking about sensitive data, be super careful handling this and putting them in CSV files!! Also make your examples more anonymous. With names like Jane Doe and SSN of 123-45-6789. Just so it's clear it's fake.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would simply adjust how much of the string I output.. So I would adjust the print line to look something like this:

```
print("***-**-"+str(ssn[7:11]))
#That should print something like: 
***-**-1234
```

You may just have to adjust the print statement slightly for your code.  However if you are looking to adjust the string completely so that data does not exist anymore you should first know strings are immutable in python.  However I would still have practically the same solution:

```
x = "***-**-"+str(ssn[7:11])
```

note: I would of put this in a comment but I cannot yet, also if this does not completely satisfy your answer could you please add the code as to how you print your output, so I can adjust my answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a regular expression

- `\d` finds all digits
- [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

  - `count=5` substitutes the first 5 digits

```py
import re

new_ssn = re.sub(r'\d', '*', '123-45-6789', count=5)
print(new_ssn)

>>> '***-**-6789'
```

### To replace all SSNs in a csv:

- Use pandas
- [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to update the entire column

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

 Emp ID           Name         DOB          SSN     State
     15  Samantha Lara  1993-09-08  848-80-7526  Colorado

# Overwrite SSN
df.SSN = df.SSN.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\d', '*', x, count=5))

 Emp ID           Name         DOB          SSN     State
     15  Samantha Lara  1993-09-08  ***-**-7526  Colorado

# Create a new column
df['SSN_hidden'] = df.SSN.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\d', '*', x, count=5))

 Emp ID           Name         DOB          SSN     State   SSN_hidden
     15  Samantha Lara  1993-09-08  848-80-7526  Colorado  ***-**-7526

# Save the data
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```